# How to denote number of summands below the expression?

Tags: pdftex, math-operators

If we want to write for example `$\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{N}\times\dots \mathbb{N}$` and below the RHS write "n copies" how we will do it in Latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I think the linked question should provide you with an answer. If it does not for some reason please comment.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you for the link. I didn't know how to search for an answer that is why I posted it as a question.

Comment: No problem. Duplicate questions are not a total waster as they also makes it easier for others in the future to find related questions.  Also, I assume that you did not mean to use `$ ... $` as this should really be in display math mode.

Comment: @PeterGrill I accidentally re-edit the post. I thought that $...$ are needed in order for the math command to be displayed as in Math Stack.

Comment: TeX.SE specifically does _not_ parse TeX and display it.  So you should correct your post as I think you want to use `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`, or `\[ ... \]` and get a display math equation -- especially since you want other text below it.